# obtain selected value from listbox with button

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a macro that creates a Button and listbox from one workbook to another. I have added a function to the button in order to populate a cell in the newly created workbook sheet with the item selected from the listbox. Unfortunately, I keep getting a object variable or with block variable not set. But is not possible since I have set this. I have also tried creating the variable outside the sub in order to make them global but no luck, Any help will be really appreciated! Here is my code:
Keep in mind this is all done in Workbook A and the button and listbox is been added to Workbook B

```
Public drpdwn As ListBox

Public sub WorkbookCreate()
...some code
 Set drpdwn = NewBook.Sheets("sheet1").ListBoxes.Add(150, 1, 100, 50)
  With drpdwn
 .AddItem "Paris"
 .AddItem "New York"
 .AddItem "London"
 .name = "drpdwn"
 End With
 Set btn = NewBook.Sheets("sheet1").Buttons.Add(49, 1, 60, 15)
 With btn
    .OnAction = "Findcity"
    .Caption = "Find"
    .name = "Find"
End With
End sub

'Function to obtain city selected
Function Findcity()
MsgBox ("clicked")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To drpdwn.ListCount - 1
    If drpdwn.Selected(i) Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = drpdwn.List(i)
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Question - you have a button in Workbook B and you specify "OnAction" as "Findcity". Is "Findcity" in Workbook B?

Comment: @Juliusz The macro is run on workbook A and created the find button on workbook B, findcity is the function being called by the button. I added a msgBox here to test that the function is being called by the button

Comment: I figured out my issue, The problem is the I am setting the variable drpdwn to equal newbook.sheets. Because of this when i click the button on the new page its trying to find this newbook but it should be activeworkbook since i am using it now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue, The problem is the I am setting the variable drpdwn to equal newbook.sheets. Because of this when I click the button on the new page its trying to find this newbook but it should be activeworkbook since i am currently using it now.
Thank you for your help!